# How can I get information on hover effect in atom editor as it displays in VScode?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, atom-editor

Is there any plugin that I have to install in Atom to get this type of information on hovering on variables, objects or functions somewhat like intellisense? It does in vscode but I want this same functionality in atom.

[image: Demo in VS Code]

Comment: Just so you know, the feature is called intellisense in VS Code.

Comment: @ifconfig dude there is no such thing in atom though it is in intelliJ and vscode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meet IntelliSense.

Go beyond syntax highlighting and autocomplete with IntelliSense, which provides smart completions based on variable types, function definitions, and imported modules.

See docs it has perfect explanation about Intellisense
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

There's an [existing issue](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/go-plus/issues/351#issuecomment-269728530) on the autocomplete package for this to be added so keep an eye on that.

For Golang Devs there's a package called [go-tip](https://atom.io/packages/go-tip) that gives you some information when you hover over functions, variables, and methods but its not a lot.